# Store a STL map into a Boost ConstBufferSequence

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast, beast-websockets

I'm trying to store a `std::map<enum, int>` in a `boost::beast::multi_buffer`. So far I've been using `boost::asio::buffer_copy` and `boost::asio::buffer` to store vectors and PODs. However, I couldn't find a way to store a STL map.

I've tried this:

```
auto t_map = std::map<CODES, int>(); // CODES is an enum type

auto t_map_size = t_map.size() * sizeof(std::pair<CODES, int>);
auto tmp_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(t_map, t_map_size); // this is not supported

auto size = boost::asio::buffer_copy(t_map_size , tmp_buffer);

boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer;
buffer.commit(size);
```

1. Is there any way to store a `std::map<enum, int>` in a `ConstBufferSequence`? (because the `boost::asio::buffer_copy` needs one)
2. If not, is there any workaround to store a `std::map<enum, int>` in a `boost::beast::multi_buffer`?

Thanks!

Comment: You can never "store" anything in a Asio buffer (or sequence) because buffers only _reference_ existing data. Any buffer refers to contiguous region of POD data, and a buffer sequence combines several of those (to support "gather" buffers  that aren't necessarily contiguous in memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your map into vector of POD, as POD choose type which can store enum + int, for example `int64_t`:

So create vector, scan your map creating items of vector using some bitwise operations and data is ready:

```
auto t_map = std::map<CODES, int>(); // CODES is an enum type

std::vector<int64_t> vec;
for (auto&& elemMap : t_map)
{
    int64_t val = elemMap.first;   // store key
    val <<= 32; // shift key
    val |= elemMap.second; // store value

    vec.push_back (val);
}

auto tmp_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(vec); // this is supported
```

Unpack vector into map should be easy.

Comment: Cool. So basically, this way is pretty much the best option to send custom types as well?

Comment: @Shmwel Input of `asio::buffer` is limited, it takes vector of POD, string, array of POD, or raw pointer + size, so some serialization method is needed to customize data before further processing. My answer showed one of possible way to do it.

Comment: I would stay away from low-level hacks to "pack" the value types. As it is, they're POD enough! You can actually be as concise as this: **[direct contiguous map copy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2464cb0087bf9fe2)**. If you look at the resulting hash digest, you can see it is exactly equivalent to the [corresponding take with manual bit-shifting hacks](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54beaa05356292ac)

Comment: @Shmwel look at existing answers that employ Json or Boost Serialization with Asio.

Comment: @sehe You are shouting at me  :D My intention was to show OP the need of some serialization method to achive his goal. I have to admit that my solution was overkill. `pair<some_int,int>` as "pod" can be stored directly into vector.

Comment: Nah I just didn't realize what bold looked like :) I usually have this `**<kbd>[Live On Coliru]...` riff (muscle memory) so the `**` comes automatic.